# How to Change ListView to GridView on Button Click in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to change my view listview to gridview and back gridview to listview on a button click.Here my product.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/main_linear_layout"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image_product"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/product_id"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="name"
           android:visibility="gone"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/product_name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="name"
          android:textColor="#166CED"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/product_price"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="1000"
           android:textColor="#D64530"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/product_discount"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="discout price"
           android:textColor="#D64530"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/product_href"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="name"
           android:visibility="gone"/>


       <RatingBar
           android:id="@+id/rating"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="gone"/>
   </LinearLayout>   </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Here My product_category.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.ProductCategory">

<!-- Header aligned to top -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FILTER"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SORT"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="257dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="257dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_product"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:listitem="@layout/product"/>

 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here My ProductCategory.java:-

```
public class ProductCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
ProductAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.Product> productsList;
private int len;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_category);


    new Product().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/products&category=369&key=test123$");

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_product);
    productsList = new ArrayList<shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.Product>();
    adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.product,productsList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public class Product extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductCategory.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status==200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    len=jsonArray.length();
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.Product product = new shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.Product();


                    product.setId(jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                    product.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    product.setPrice(jsonObject1.getString("pirce"));
                    product.setDiscountprice(jsonObject1.getString("discountprice"));
                    product.setHref(jsonObject1.getString("href"));
                    product.setThumb(jsonObject1.getString("thumb"));
                    product.setRating(jsonObject1.getString("rating"));

                    productsList.add(product);
                }
                return true;
            }

        }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(!aVoid){
            Toast.makeText(ProductCategory.this, "Data is not Parsed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.product,productsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Here My ProductAdapter.java:-

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

ArrayList<Product> productsList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> object) {
    super(context, resource, object);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    productsList = object;
    Resource = resource;
    //   this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

        holder.imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_product);
        holder.tvId = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
        holder.tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        holder.tvPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        holder.tvDiscount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_discount);
        holder.tvHref = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_href);
        holder.tvRating = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    new DownlaoadImageTask(holder.imageView).execute(productsList.get(position).getThumb());
    holder.tvId.setText(productsList.get(position).getId());
    holder.tvName.setText(productsList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(productsList.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.tvDiscount.setText(productsList.get(position).getDiscountprice());
    holder.tvHref.setText(productsList.get(position).getHref());
    holder.tvRating.setNumStars(Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(position).getRating()));
    return v;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView  tvId;
    public TextView  tvName;
    public TextView  tvPrice;
    public TextView  tvDiscount;
    public TextView  tvHref;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public RatingBar  tvRating;
}
private class DownlaoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownlaoadImageTask(ImageView bmImage){
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try{
            InputStream in  = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return  mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

}
```

I am new in android developing Please Help me thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understood right,you just need use Frame layout  and Set the Visibility for the grid view or List accordingly using .setVisibility(true/false) on button click listener and if it is not working please give some info what u exactly want to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456602/5973946

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add both ListView and GridView and set GridView android:visibility="gone"

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_product"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:listitem="@layout/product"/>

  <GridView
      android:id="@+id/list_productGV"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

on button click change visibilty of ListView to gone and GridView to visible and vice versa

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding the code you mentioned. I.e. the attribute of visibility to the listview or gridview, and the Java method you mention using.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can try to use `GridView` only and change it's columns number using `gridview.setNumColumns(n);`. For `ListView` imitation just use `n = 0`.

2.Another option is to use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

```
final int gridSpanCount = 4;
mImagesGrid = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, gridSpanCount);
mImagesGrid.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mSwitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_btn);
mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (mLayoutManager.getSpanCount() == gridSpanCount){
            mLayoutManager.setSpanCount(1);
        }
        else {
            mLayoutManager.setSpanCount(gridSpanCount);
        }
    }
}
```